# HERE maps android premium Map.Projection issue?

Tags: android, here-api

In am trying to display the full map on the mobile screen.But when i use

> `hereMap.setProjectionMode(Map.Projection.MERCATOR);`

[image]
Somehow when doing **complete zoom out** i can see **square map** for the world in the center and **blue padding** in the **entire screen** . How can i **fix** this issue? 
I only want to display complete map on the screen without any projection type.
I have verified with IOS demo app for premium where the map looks proper .

This issue is in Android app .The Square in middle also can  be moved up or down. I dont want such thing to appear on the UI.

In IOS the Map is perfectly aligned on the screen without such blue padding.

Comment: Before any negative reviews . Please share your opinions on it .I have verified this with IOS DEMO where its perfect ,it does not show the world map in the middle of the screen when minimum zoom is done . And it also shows weird blue padding all over the square map.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the SDK 3.10. Here is this issue already fixed.

Comment: Its still present in 3.10 .The padding is not completely removed .There is padding on top and bottom .